# Facebook's App Invite Error

Tags: android, facebook, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I am trying to implement **Facebook's App Invite** in Android and IOs as explained [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/android). I have also created a static html page that contains the meta-data as mentioned in the tutorial.

```
<meta property="al:ios:app_name" content="Couchin'">
<meta property="al:android:url" content="couchinapp://invite_from_fb?referral=123456789">
<meta property="al:ios:url" content="couchinapp://invite_from_fb?referral=123456789"><meta property="al:ios:app_store_id" content="123456789"><meta property="al:android:app_name" content="Couchin">
<meta property="al:android:package" content="com.makeitnow.justfollow.sociallog">
<meta property="al:web:url" content="http://www.couchinapp.com/myapp.html">
```

But when i try to send invite from my app i am getting the following error..

> Missing App Link URL The app link used with this invite does not contain an Android or iOS URL. Developers are required to enter a URL for at least one platform.

I can't figure out the issue. Please help :(

**P.S** : The links added in the meta-data are fake. But i believe it shouldn't be problem while sending invites. It might create an issue when user click on the invites but that i will handle.

**UPDATE :**

> After updating the required meta-tags, it was still
>   showing the same error in the mobile app. To solve it, i went to
>   developers.facebook.com/tools/debug, added my AppLink URL and clicked
>   on **"fetch new scrap information"**. Apparently mobile app was fetching
>   the old data from the cache of the AppLink URL even after updating it.
>   It's a Facebook's bug i guess.

Comment: You can put your static html url into https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ and it will tell you what our parser sees.

Comment: @MingLi  It says "The 'og:type' property is required, but not present.". I think "Type" field is not mandatory.

Comment: IIRC, you might need a title instead of type. So make sure you either have a <title> tag, or an og:title meta tag.

Comment: Thanks @MingLi. It worked.

Answer (score 3):

This will help you setup or edit your **ApplinkURL**:
https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/?platform=app-links-host

After you configure all your settings correctly you'll end up with something like:

> Here is the App Link URL you created: https://fb.me/12345...

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. But i don't want the Facebook hosted AppLink. I want  to create a custom one hosted on my website page.

Comment: I have one custom "app link" in my server (with a "scheme", "host" and "pathPrefix") that I use as "data" inside an "intent-filter" (to open my app by clicking in a URL inside a registration e-mail for example). Then with the Facebook webtool I've used a concatenated string with all that data. I don't know if there's other way to do so, but maybe this could be what you want. You still have your path hosted in your server but in the end you'll have a facebook hosted AppLink (using yours).